# Magento - edit multiple original tables of magento

Tags: magento-1.8, database, mysql

I want to edit some tables of magento and I've made a module to do that.
For example I want to edit table "catalog_product_bundle_price_index".

Here is the global section of my config.xml :

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <mymodule_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_setup>
        <mymodule_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_read>
        <mymodule_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_write>
    </resources>
</global>
```

And here is the code in mysql4-install-1.0.0.php :

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$tables = array(
        $installer->getTable('bundle/price_index') => array(
                'columns' => array(
                        'min_price' => array(
                                'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                                'scale'     => 4,
                                'precision' => 16,
                                'nullable'  => false,
                                'comment'   => 'Min Price'
                        ),
                        'max_price' => array(
                                'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                                'scale'     => 4,
                                'precision' => 16,
                                'nullable'  => false,
                                'comment'   => 'Max Price'
                        )
                ),
                'comment' => 'Catalog Product Bundle Price Index'
        )
);



$installer->getConnection()->modifyTables($tables);
$installer->endSetup();
```

but it does not work, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to clear your cache by deletiting everything inside var/cache folder. May be some kind of DDL cache is in place.

Comment: It does not work, the fields are still decimal(12,4)!

Comment: I think you should use  modifyColumn()  http://abhayraj4u.blogspot.com/2013/03/magento-alter-table-in-magento-setup.html

Comment: I just delete the module and install it again and everything worked perfect!!!! 
I don't know why, but it seems to be correct!
btw, thank you for your concern @EvgeniIvanov :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the problem was, that you first added the setup to the config.xml which added the information "setup ran" to `core_resource`. In `core_resource` is saved which version of your module is installed.

To run the setup again you have to reset the version number or delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using the `changeColumn` method.
Here is the method signature:

```
public function changeColumn($tableName, $oldColumnName, $newColumnName, $definition, $flushData = false, $schemaName = null);
```

it should go something like this:

```
$installer->getConnection()->changeColumn($installer->getTable('bundle/price_index'), 'min_price', 'min_price', array(
                                'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                                'scale'     => 4,
                                'precision' => 16,
                                'nullable'  => false,
                                'comment'   => 'Min Price'
                        ));
```

I haven't tested though.